# EXCEL - HOW TO MAKE DATA ONLY 'F' or 'M' in column, and calculate amount

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Here is my spreadsheet:

https://snag.gy/8gAoPj.jpg

how do i make it so that data entered in the gender column can only be M or F
and then create a button that calculates the amount of Males and Females?

Comment: Add data validation to the cells to constrain the values. The total can then be found using `COUNTIF`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us the code that you have? So that we could help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Column E (entirely)
Menu Data-->Data Validation-->Settings Tab -->
    Allow: List
    Source: M,F
```

You'll get a combobox at each cell of row E.
To get the number of Males, type this formula in any cell of the worksheet:

```
=COUNTIF(E:E, "M")
```

Similarly for **F**emales.